# MSI Authentication in Visual studio

Tags: authentication, azure-managed-identity

I have tried to trigger azure function using service principal, and i didnt have permission to get the secret key. how to do MSI Authentication in Visual studio for connecting to azure function?

Answer (score 0):

MSI, also known as Managed Identities, are an Azure resource. You can assign a managed identity directly to your Azure functions app, which will then allow the functions app to authenticate as that identity. This lets the function app access resources such as Azure Key Vault or Storage.

Managed identities cannot be used outside of Azure: so you cannot use it in Visual studio to connect to your azure function.